# Can i publish my javascript file in minimal mode and hard to read by others? like jquery library

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sample my code

```
function doit(){
  var num=num1+num2
}
```

After publish i want like in abstract format. Like -

```
function a(){var b=c+d}; //should not be easily readable
```

Comment: Yes, [minify](http://jscompress.com/)/[uglify](https://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs) it. Use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)/[Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) task runner to automate this process or add the package/plugin/add-on in your editor to make it on a single button click.

Comment: For that you have to compress the js code. You can check YUI compressor ,Google Closure Compiler,JSMin.

Comment: @Tushar can you give me reference link where i can convert it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes all these minifiers do is rename functions and variables to obfuscated names so they have no meaning to anyone reading them. Then they remove all indentation, line returns, and unnecesary spaces. I personally use jsMIN and ocassionally this online tool. http://javascript-minifier.com/